# how to trim "enter key" in a string

Tags: java, jsp

String strFCKeditor1 = request.getParameter("FCKeditor1");

Comment: can you please elaborate more on trimming the 'enter key'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String strFCKeditor1 = request.getParameter("FCKeditor1").replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
```

You also need to replace the `\r` and/or `\n\r` (hence the regex), not just `\n` as stated in the other answer, since you don't know whether your user is using Windows / Mac OSX / Linux.

Comment: shouldn't it be `request.getParameter("FCKeditor1").toString().replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");` ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi 
No: As can be read here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

getParameter returns a String, not an Object

Answer (score 1):

```
strFCKeditor1.replaceAll("\n","");//this will replace all \n with blank string
```

Comment: i just completed my CMS just becuase of ur help. thanks man u make my work so easy. thanks again:-)

Answer (score -2):

From your question i assume you want to remove the newline characters from the end of your string.

Use -

`StringUtils.chomp(str);`

http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.4353